# How to split the input data into variables

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to read data from an input file, split them up, and put them into variables.

input data is below. 3, 4, 4 mean "size," 1, 1 ,1 mean "column," 1, 1, 2 mean "row."

```
3 1 1
4 1 1
4 1 2
```

```
ifstream input; // stream for input file
input.open(argv[1]); // open input file

string in_str;
string size, column, row; // input data

while(getline(input, in_str)) {
    stringstream ss(in_str);
    ss >> size >> column >> row;
}
```

I was able to get these data and put them into variables; however, if there are more columns and rows like input data below, I don't know how to put 8 into size, put 2 and 7 into columns, and put 3 and 1 into rows.

```
8 2 3 7 1
```

I tried and searched, but I couldn't find how to solve it. I would appreciate any solutions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that you have to iterate over the items of the line.

Answer (score 0):

First:

You need to understand that similar data are stored in `std::array`s or `std::vector`s or other containers.

And data that are not similar, but belong togther are stored for example in `structs`

If you look at your data, then you will note that the size is not static, but dynamic. To store dynamic data in C++, `std::vector` is used. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) about it.

From this we can derive the following:

"row" and "column" are somehow belonging together. We will put them into a `struct`. Let's call it "ColRow". There may be any number of row/column pairs. Hence, we will put the `struct` into a `std::vector`. Later, we wll call this "colRows".

A line of data has the "size" as first parameter and then the above `std::vector` of `struct`s. We call this `struct` "LineData"

In your source data contains many lines and we will create a `std::vector` of "LineData" and call it "data".

Then we need in a loop the lines. For each line we will extract first the "size" and then in a second, inner loop, the column/row pairs.

One potential solution could be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct ColRow {
    int column{};
    int row{};
};
struct LineData {
    int size;
    std::vector<ColRow> colRows;
};

std::stringstream testFileStream{ R"(3 1 1 
4 1 1
4 1 2
8 2 3 7 1
10 1 11 2 12 3 13 4 14)" };

int main() {
    std::string input{};
    int column{}, row{};

    std::vector<LineData> data{};

    while (std::getline(testFileStream, input)) {
        std::istringstream iss(input);
        data.push_back({});
        iss >> data.back().size;
        while (iss >> column >> row) {
            data.back().colRows.push_back({column, row});
        }
    }
    // Debug output
    for (const LineData& ld : data) {
        std::cout << "\n\nSize: " << ld.size << '\n';
        for (const ColRow& cr : ld.colRows)
            std::cout << "Col: " << cr.column << "\t Row: " << cr.row << '\n';
    }
}
```

But in real CPP we would use a more object oriented approach and notice, that only the object should know how to read or write its elements. For that we would put read and write procedures als in a class.

We will use the standard C++ exttraction iand insertion operators `>>´ and` <<` andoverride them for our purposes. This will then allow for a very simple main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct ColRow {
    // Data
    int column{};
    int row{};

    // extractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, ColRow& cr) {
        return is >> cr.column >> cr.row;
    }
    // inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const ColRow& cr) {
        return os << "Column: " << cr.column << "\tRow: " << cr.row;
    }
};
struct LineData {
    // Data
    int size{};
    std::vector<ColRow> colRows;

    // extractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, LineData& ld) {
        std::string line{}; ld.colRows.clear();
        std::getline(is, line); std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> ld.size;
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<ColRow>(iss), {}, std::back_inserter(ld.colRows));
        return is;
    }
    // Inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const LineData& ld) {
        os << "\nSize: " << ld.size << '\n';
        std::copy(ld.colRows.begin(), ld.colRows.end(), std::ostream_iterator<ColRow>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};
struct Data {
    // Data
    std::vector<LineData> rows{};
    // extractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Data& d) {
        d.rows.clear();
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<LineData>(is), {}, std::back_inserter(d.rows));
        return is;
    }
    // Inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Data& d) {
        std::copy(d.rows.begin(), d.rows.end(), std::ostream_iterator<LineData>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }

};

std::stringstream testFileStream{ R"(3 1 1 
4 1 1
4 1 2
8 2 3 7 1
10 1 11 2 12 3 13 4 14)" };

int main() {

    Data data{};

    testFileStream >> data;

    std::cout << data;

}
```